# Adafruit_NeoPixel objects abnormal behavior when used in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, arduino, adafruit

I've been having problems trying to work out how to loop through an array of Adafruit_NeoPixel objects.
But I cant for the life of me get my head aroud what is going wrong. Ive looked up this issue on google and trough both Ardrino and stack over flow ive tryed adapting the code to what ive seen other people have done (for example instead of listing the adafruit_neopixles objects in the array,create the neopixles inside the array) to get it to work and still I have no luck.

so heres an simple example: this script should make the first 6 Leds light up in green blue

```
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>

Adafruit_NeoPixel strips[] = {
  Adafruit_NeoPixel(32, 5, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800),
  Adafruit_NeoPixel(32, 6, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800),
  Adafruit_NeoPixel(32, 7, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800),
};

#define NUMSTRIPS (sizeof(strips)/sizeof(strips[0]))

void setup() {
     //Edit2
         Serial.begin(115200);
     //end Edit2
  
  for(int i=0; i<NUMSTRIPS; i++)
  {
    strips[i].begin();
    strips[i].setBrightness(255); //adjust brightness here
    
    /*This is code that ive added in AFTER i made the orgional post to see if it had any difference   
    */
        for (int j=0; j<10;j++){
          strips[0].setPixelColor(j, 0,100,0);
      }
    
     /* End of edited code
     */
    strips[i].show(); // Initialize all pixels to 'off'
  }
  //Edit2
    Serial.println("Loop end");
  //End Edit2

  //strips[0].begin();
  strips[0].setBrightness(255);
  strips[0].setPixelColor(0, 0,100,255);
  strips[0].setPixelColor(1, 0,100,255);
  strips[0].setPixelColor(2, 0,100,255);
  strips[0].setPixelColor(3, 0,100,255);
  strips[0].setPixelColor(4, 0,100,255);
  strips[0].setPixelColor(5, 0,100,255);
  strips[0].show();
}
```

However that does nothing no led's light up at all. *-WHY!?*
Yet when I comment out the For loop and un-comment the `strips[0].begin` it does work.
So why is this? what am I not able to understand?

EDIT: So I tried changing a few things in my code to test if it had any affect
i added in

```
    for (int j=0; j<10;j++){
          strips[0].setPixelColor(j, 0,100,0);
      }
```

it worked inside the loop but now anything after the loop no longer works.

EDIT 2: so after using serial i found out that the device is crashing when the loop ends. So why would that be?.

Edit 3:
First I would like to say sorry to ocrdu they tried to edit this but still not quite had the right idea.

Second I want to say that half the problem has been worked out the abnormal behavior was caused by the micro controller crashing when ever the strips were being illiterate through. As for the why that is still what I need help to understand.

So I made it through 1 loop now before it crashes so progress? I took Botje's advice and I used `strips[i].numPixels();` instead of using a fixed value

however I decided to do a few more tests to see if I had fixed the problem and well it crashed before test 2 even got to start. Here is the new code.

```
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>

Adafruit_NeoPixel strips[] = {
  Adafruit_NeoPixel(32, 5, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800),
  Adafruit_NeoPixel(32, 6, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800),
  Adafruit_NeoPixel(32, 7, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800),
};

#define NUMSTRIPS (sizeof(strips)/sizeof(strips[0]))

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  
  Serial.println("1st Test Do a loop with out crashing over all the strips");
  for(int i=0; i<NUMSTRIPS; i++)
  {
    strips[i].begin();
    strips[i].setBrightness(255);
    for (int j=0; j<strips[i].numPixels();j++){
          strips[i].setPixelColor(j, 0,100,0);
          Serial.println(j);
      }
    Serial.println("b4 show");
    strips[i].show(); 
  }
  Serial.println("Loop end");
  Serial.println("If you are reading this then the microcontroller did not crash on 1st Test");



  delay(150);



  Serial.println("2nd Test Do a loop with out crashing over 1 strip");
  for (int k=0; k<strips[0].numPixels();k++)
  {
    strips[0].setPixelColor(k, 0,100,255);
    strips[0].show();
    Serial.println(k);
  }
  Serial.println("Loop end");
  Serial.println("If you are reading this then the microcontroller did not crash the 2nd Test");



  delay(150);



  Serial.println("3rd Test Do a loop changing onley 6 pixles on 1 strip with out crashing");
  for (int l=0; l<=5; l++)
  {
    strips[0].setPixelColor(l, 200,0,0);
    strips[0].show();
    Serial.println(l);
  }
  Serial.println("Loop end");
  Serial.println("If you are reading this then the microcontroller did not crash the 3rd Test");
}
```

Comment: You don't call setPixelColor in your for loop. If I understand the documentation correctly, all set Brightness does is multiply the stored pixel colors when you call show. I'm willing to bet the default pixel color is black.

Comment: because it sets the color outside the loop. but i tested it inside the loop just to check and still had the same issue

Comment: That is not in code you showed. Please show actual code.

Comment: what version of the code am i suposed to post? ive trryed atleast 7 different ways of having setpixle inside the loop since your first post

the one moste intresting is 
    `for (int j=0; j<10;j++){
          strips[0].setPixelColor(j, 0,100,0);
      }`
as that one works bvut anything out side the loop no longer works

Comment: Shouldn't you loop up to `strips[i].numPixels()`? If there are less than 10 pixels available the `j<10` loop scribbles over other memory and can cause a crash.

Comment: You initialise 32 LEDs per strip, you want to light up 6 LEDs, and you loop to 10 LEDs. Also, with all the edits and experiments, things aren't getting any clearer. I edited in the code at the bottom of your post I assume you want to get to work; please try it and tell us what it does or doesn't do. It may take a while for the edit to be approved.

Comment: Botje I will defentley look into that when i get home

Comment: Ocrdu the strips are 32 leds long. Ive just been slotting in a few leds just for testing. This project i only wrote to help me work out an issue for a bigger project. The edits are just some if the testing i tried to see what's going on

Comment: Strange can't edit my post from my phone. Anyway after sleeping on it i realised that the problem is that the devices (yes i tested it on different microcontrollers a nano and a mcu) can't handle illiterating  through an array of adafruit_neopixles without crashing. Could be to do with what botje said about overwriting other memory so I will try that first but ill comment again if no luck.

Comment: So I tried your advice it kinda worked but still have issues. see edit 3

Comment: Creating an `Adafruit_Neopixel` object does a [malloc() for the pixels](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_NeoPixel/blob/899b163a76a92f0e1f51b75ec23cf103afb7c164/Adafruit_NeoPixel.cpp#L126-L137), perhaps that is failing due to exhausted heap? You can check that indirectly by inspecting the value from `numPixels()`. Is that your whole program? I'm getting a bit confused by the edits.BTW, your debugging will also be consuming memory, might be worth using `F()` macro on the strings in the `Serial.print()` statements.

Comment: I just cut and paste the code, added an empty `loop` function and it compiled and ran on an Arduino Uno Clone. I don't have any NeoPixels attached. How are yours powered? 96 NeoPixels at full power is a fair bit of current...

Comment: The power is fine the issue happens even when my friend tested it on his esp with no lights plugged in. Like i said it works on nanos and unos but not 3rd party bords

Comment: Btw I tried to look up what a malloc() is. Still don't reay understand it but I'm assuming its some way of managing memory on a heap. Genley when i want a dynamic array ill use a vector and that's about as far as my knowledge goes in that area.

Comment: And oh 1 more thing no its not the my whole program its just a part that I extracted into a new project to see if i can get it to work. The whole program itself contains a multitude of functions for animating led patterns and stuff. Hence why no loop function there

Comment: Oh i see some one deleted my answer i said there that  So I Tested the changes on my nano and it worked. I sent the code to a friend he tested it on his uno and it worked but he tested it on his esp8266 and that just made it crash. so it looks like it only works on Arduino boards.

Comment: Perhaps worth re-titling this to reflect the question is really about why something would work on an Arduino Uno and not an ESP8266 based board.

Comment: I've not used an ESP8266 but look like 3.3V? Are your RGB pixels specified to work with 3.3V inputs or are you level shifting them? The ones I have used empirically work but I've never looked into whether this is guaranteed by the spec. to work. For Adafruit NeoPixels, https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-neopixel-uberguide/best-practices actually states: "NeoPixels powered by 5v require a 5V data signal. If using a 3.3V microcontroller you must use a logic level shifter such as a 74AHCT125 or 74HCT245. (If you are powering your NeoPixels with 3.7v like from a LiPoly, a 3.3v data signal is OK)"

Comment: Its not to do with power. Like I said the issue still happens even when there is no leds attached. Besides the leds are powered on a 5v rail while the boards are powered off there usb inputs. Also just to add I've used these leds with the controllers in question many tines for weeks nonstop b4 with no issue. I know this set up works. The difference is the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've fixed this issue by swapping out the adafruit liabery with fastled no more crashing or abnormal behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Long time after the question but maybe it can help someone:
You must indicate the "instance" for the setPixelColor and then it will works.

So:

```
strips[idx_strip].setPixelColor(idx_pixel, strips[idx_strip].Color(10, 0, 5));
```

Notice one "detail": the total number of pixels the LIB seems to be able to handle is 256. But this number is **NOT** for one instance but for all instances...

Meaning this will work:

```
Adafruit_NeoPixel strips[] = {
  Adafruit_NeoPixel(32, 5, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800),
  Adafruit_NeoPixel(32, 6, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800),
  Adafruit_NeoPixel(32, 7, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800),
};
```

But with that, only the first instance will work!

```
Adafruit_NeoPixel strips[] = {
  Adafruit_NeoPixel(256, 5, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800),
  Adafruit_NeoPixel(256, 6, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800),
  Adafruit_NeoPixel(256, 7, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800),
};
```